# Как настроить перенос слов целиком в TextView?

Tags: android

Из базы берется текст и вставляется в TextView, если текст большой, то все не вмещается в одну строку, происходит перенос строки, но проблема в том, что слова могут переноситься частями (половина слова в одной строке, половина в другой). Как сделать чтобы слово переносилось целиком на новую строку? 
Вот так выглядит Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvKod"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >

</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:textSize="12sp" >
</TextView>
```

</LinearLayout>

Comment: Оно по умолчанию должно переноситься целиком на новую строку...    
Приведите пример того, что не переносится...